# Error: value scala is not a package

Tags: scala

I worked on a certain project using Scala, Maven and IntelliJ.
Everything worked fine, until I had to format my computer and re-install everything. Now when I try to run the same project I worked on, I get these errors:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: List(package scala, package scala)
scala.reflect.runtime.ReflectError: value scala is not a package
```

Do any of you know what it means?

Comment: i am not sure how you ended up with the `List(package scala, package scala)` . Can you quickly write up a simple Scala Object and test out basic collection operations in the same setup and then share the code with us ?

Comment: are you using the same JDK and Scala version as before?

Comment: I had same situation, the problem was that I tried to run Scala 2.11 code on Scala 2.10 environment

Answer (score 1):

Are you doing multithreading runtime reflection and which version of Scala do you use ?
It seems related to thread safety of Scala.
Unfortunately, in Scala 2.10 reflection is not thread safe. Read more:

http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/thread-safety.html